# NSAttributedString not obeying foregroundColor

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit

I have a `UIViewRepresentable` that uses `NSAttributedString` to set the stroke of the given text.

It works fine except for one thing: the text has no fill -- only stroke.

```
struct StrokedText: UIViewRepresentable {
    let text: String
    let width: CGFloat
    let color: Color
    let fontSize: CGFloat
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UILabel {
        let attributedStringParagraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        attributedStringParagraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignment.center
        let attributedString = NSAttributedString(
            string: text,
            attributes:[
                NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle: attributedStringParagraphStyle,
                NSAttributedString.Key.strokeWidth: fontSize * 0.05,
                NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white,
                NSAttributedString.Key.strokeColor: UIColor(color),
                NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name:"Coiny-Regular", size: fontSize)!
            ]
        )

        let strokeLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect.zero)
        strokeLabel.attributedText = attributedString
        strokeLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        strokeLabel.sizeToFit()
        strokeLabel.center = CGPoint.init(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
        return strokeLabel
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UILabel, context: Context) {}
}
```

Usage:

```
struct MyView: View {
   var body: some View {
     GeometryReader { geo in
        StrokedText(text: "STORE", width: 0.5, color: Color.black, fontSize: geo.size.width * 0.08)
     }
   }
}
```

If `.foregroundColor` doesn't work, how can I set the fill color for the text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This because you are setting a stroke color to your text. All you need is to set a negative value to your stroke:

```
.strokeWidth: fontSize * -0.05
```